# How to show $- D_u f = D_{-u} f$

Tags: limits, derivatives, partial-derivative, limits-without-lhopital

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}$.If $D_uf$ exists for a unit vector
>   $u \in \mathbb{R}^p$, then show that  $$- D_u f = D_{-u} f$$

If $f$ was differentiable, the directional derivative in the direction of $u$, would be 
$$\nabla f \cdot u,$$
so from that we could have shown the result easily.However, since it is not the case, I directly tried to use the definition of directional derivative, i.e I have assumed that
$$lim_{h\to 0} f(c+ hu) - f(c) / h, \quad \forall c\in \mathbb{R}^p,$$
exists, and we can rewrite it as 
$$lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(c + |h|c) - f(c)}{|h|} = lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{-f(c - |h|u) + f(c)}{|h|}. \quad (1)$$
Then define t = |h|, hence
$$lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{f(c+ tu) - f(c)}{t} = lim_{t\to O^+} \frac{-f(c-tu) + f(c)}{t}. \quad (2).$$

With $(2)$, I have the one side of the limit of $D_{-u} f(c)$, but how to get the other side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$D_uf(c)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(c+ hu)-f(c)}{h}$$
exists (means it is the same value for either $h<0$ or $h>0$ ) for any unit vector $u$. Look at
$$D_{-u}f(c))=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(c-hu)-f(c)}{h}\quad\text{exist}$$
$$=-\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(c+tu)-f(c)}{t}=-D_uf(c),$$
where we have used the substitution $t=-h$.

Comment: $h$ infront of $u$ can take both negative and positive values since you assumed $D_uf$ exists.